# Clicking Link to choose value and submit form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have an existing form using drop down menu with submit button and it works fine.

I would like to add direct links for select categories links or images outside of the form - how can I accomplish this?

My attempt below does not work.
Any suggestions are appreciated!

```
<form method="post" action="page.php?cat" id="searchcat"> 
    <select name="Categories">
        <option selected>Browse...</option>
        <option value="j001">Option 1</option>
        <option value="j002">Option 2</option>
        <option value="j003">3</option>
        <option value="j004">4</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>

<a onclick="SelectItemByValue(document.getElementById('searchcat'), j004);">
    Click here to submit option#4
</a>

<script>
function SelectItemByValue(element, value) {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        var length = element.options.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (element.options[i].value === value) {
                element.selectedIndex = i;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the unquoted `j004` is invalid use: `'j004'` instead

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. So it should be `SelectItemByValue`. The missing quotes is also correct. Also, there is a missing `=` after `onclick`.

Comment: Please add nesting/spacing.

Comment: `document.getElementById('searchcat')`. That will return the form but you want the select. Give the select an id and use `document.getElementById('Categories')`. https://jsfiddle.net/5ery3u7v/2/

Comment: @JeremyC - You can use this site to quickly indent the code so it's easier to follow.  Appearantly, it works on html as well. http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Thank you for the typo corrections! in the code, i didnt miss the =, it just didnt copy over - but the rest, I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward, take a look at the lines with `changed`, both in html and javascript:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php?cat" id="searchcat"> 
    <select name="Categories" id='cats'>  <!-- changed -->
        <option selected>Browse...</option>
        <option value="j001">Option 1</option>
        <option value="j002">Option 2</option>
        <option value="j003">3</option>
        <option value="j004">4</option>
        ...
    </select>
</form>

<a onclick="SelectItemByValue(document.getElementById('searchcat'), 'j004');"> <!-- changed -->
    Click here to submit option#4
</a>

<script>
function SelectItemByValue(form, value) { // changed
    var sel = form.elements.namedItem('cats'); // changed
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
        var length = sel.options.length; // changed
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (sel.options[i].value === value) { // changed
                sel.selectedIndex = i;
                form.submit(); // changed
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Your code had some problems, such as:

- You were missing `'` on `j004`, so: `'j004'`;
- Your element variable didn't refer to the `<select>` element; and
- You were missing the actual call to submit the form.

---

You mentioned that you have a button, like so:

```
<input id="search2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
```

But in my tests, naming a button as `submit` caused the script to stop working. This code worked for me:

```
<button name='sent'>Search</button>
```

**But be advised** in case you are using the button as isset: If the form is sent via the anchor, there will be no `sent` to check if `isset`...

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! If I could give you bonus points, I would

Comment: @JeremyC, I'm glad to help. Just edited my answer :)